# jQuery: How can I use event delegation with classes added to nested divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to code this poem with nested divs and basic jQuery. My idea was to start with one div of class `.active` that has `display: block` and all the other `div`s being children of the first `div` with `display: none`. Now, when you click on the first `div`, it removes the class `.active` from itself (adds to itself class `.static` that for now just changes color) and adds `.active` to its child. In effect, a child `div` becomes visible. Then you click that child to reveal its child and so on until the end of the poem:

```
$(".active").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("static");
  $(this).children("div").addClass("active")
});
```

Only the first div's class `.active` exists in the DOM when the script is loaded. The click works on the first div and is ignored on the next, as in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4ygfrtgb/1/

I tried event delegation like this:

```
$("div").on("click", ".active", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("static");
  $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
});
```

However, then not even the first `div` reacts to a click. I understand that delegation works on children of elements, while I'm trying to call a class of the same element.

So is there a way to target elements by a class that is added after the DOM is loaded?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Thanks @Yang Shun formatting my post! Looks so much more legible! :)

Comment: Welcome, have a look at the answer and see if it works for you (:

Comment: In your jsfiddle, shouldn't it be `$(this).find(".active").find(".static")` (emphasis on the dots) ?

Comment: Definitely! I didn't even get there yet because my code broke before that. :) Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer with a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ygfrtgb/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing event delegation correctly... Read more about it [here](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

In event delegation, you attach the click handler to the parent and add a target child selector to respond to that event. In your case, you are attaching it to the target element itself.

Attach the click handler to some element that is a parent of the first `div` (you might want to be more specific rather than use `body`).

```
$("body").on("click", "div.active", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("active").addClass("static");
  $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
});
```

Updated the JSFiddle to show that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/4ygfrtgb/2/.

Comment: It works indeed! I put everything into a `#wrapper` `div` to avoid events on the `body`. May I take advantage of your expertise once more? My second idea was to be able to fold the poem up from any level by clicking on `.static` that would remove any visible classes from all children of the clicked `div`. And I broke it again: https://jsfiddle.net/4ygfrtgb/3/ Why? Can't I delegate two different events on two different classes inside the same parent? Many thanks!

Comment: You can, but they can interfere with each other and you'll have to use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from propagating to the parent elements. Have fixed the JSFiddle again for your next requirement: https://jsfiddle.net/yangshun/4ygfrtgb/4/

Comment: You are THE BEST!!! :D Thanks a million! I remember `stopPropagation()` from that course, tryjQuery, but I thought, When would I _ever_ need to use that? And here we are now... Things are slowly starting to come together in my jQuery education. I'll read up on bubbling, and capturing. Thanks again!

Comment: You're most welcome! ^_^ My recommendation would be not to use a parent children relationship for the subsequent lines in the poem. A sibling relationship would work better (and you wouldn't have to add any code to prevent event propagation). The children poem lines are currently also being indented as it goes deeper, a sibling relationship would prevent that from happening.

Comment: Ha! That was my first thought too, especially that keeping track of closing tags in this mess has been giving me a headache. The catch, though, is that this is only one branch on this poem. I'm using siblings to reveal two `div`s on one line. You then click on only one, and that takes you to its children -- a completely different poem. Like choose your own adventure. But maybe I can invert my design and use children for those crossroads. I'll figure it out and post the finished poem here! :D