toggleClass works once, but not in every needed scenario
My toggle class doesn't work in a specific scenario (I've also tried it with addClass and removeClass but still did noting.
I've made 5 bars, with a button that opens up the bar and closes the other one that is open. When you press the close button on an open bar, I want that bar to close (that works) and want the bar on the left (grey) to open up again. So that when all colored bars are closed, the grey one is always open.
Hope anyone knows what's wrong with my script.
Code:


$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".b1 tab").click(function() {
    $(".b1").toggleClass("open");
    $(".b2, .b3, .b4, .b5").removeClass("open");
  });

  $(".b2 tab").click(function() {
    $(".b2").toggleClass("open");
    $(".b1, .b3, .b4, .b5").removeClass("open");
  });

  $(".b3 tab").click(function() {
    $(".b3").toggleClass("open");
    $(".b1, .b2, .b4, .b5").removeClass("open");
  });

  $(".b4 tab").click(function() {
    $(".b4").toggleClass("open");
    $(".b1, .b2, .b3, .b5").removeClass("open");
  });

  $(".b5 tab").click(function() {
    $(".b5").toggleClass("open");
    $(".b1, .b2, .b3, .b4").removeClass("open");
  });

  $(".b2.open tab").click(function() {
    $(".b1").toggleClass("open");
  });

});
/* Standard values */

:root {
  --unit: calc(100vh / 20);
  --bar-close: calc(4 * var(--unit));
  --bar-open: calc(100vw - (20 * var(--unit)));
  --padding: calc(2 * var(--unit));
  --icon: calc(var(--unit) / 2);
  --green: rgba(0, 90, 50, 1);
  --red: rgba(255, 5, 15, 1);
  --white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  --gray: rgba(190, 190, 190, 1);
  --blue: rgba(20, 20, 100, 1);
  --yellow: rgba(250, 200, 50, 1);
  --brown: rgba(110, 75, 40, 1);
  --orange: rgba(250, 110, 0, 1);
  background-color: var(--white) !important;
  color: var(--gray) !important;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: calc(var(--unit) / 2) !important;
  line-height: calc(var(--unit) / 2 * 1) !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* END Standard values */


/* General Values */

icon {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: var(--icon);
  height: var(--icon);
}

icon svg {
  width: var(--icon);
  height: var(--icon);
  fill: var(--white);
}


/* END General Values */

html {
  background: red;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--white) !important;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100vw - (4 * var(--unit)));
  height: calc(100vh - (4 * var(--unit)));
  margin: calc(2 * var(--unit));
}

bar {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: var(--bar-close);
  height: calc(100vh - (2 * var(--padding)));
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}

bar.open {
  width: var(--bar-open);
}

bar.b1 {
  background: var(--gray);
}

bar.b1 tab {
  background: var(--white);
}

bar.b1 tab icon svg {
  fill: var(--gray);
}

bar.b2 {
  background: var(--orange);
}

bar.b2 tab {
  background: var(--orange);
}

bar.b3 {
  background: var(--green);
}

bar.b3 tab {
  background: var(--red);
}

bar.b4 {
  background: var(--brown);
}

bar.b4 tab {
  background: var(--brown);
}

bar.b5 {
  background: var(--blue);
}

bar.b5 tab {
  background: var(--yellow);
}

bar inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - (2 * var(--padding)));
  height: 100%;
  padding: var(--padding);
}

bar tab {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: var(--bar-close);
  height: calc(100% / 2);
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: red;
}

bar tab icon {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(3.5 * var(--icon));
  right: calc(3.5 * var(--icon));
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

bar.open tab icon {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <wrapper>

    <bar class="b1">
      <inner>
        test
      </inner>
      <tab>
        <icon class="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/></svg></icon>
      </tab>
    </bar>

    <bar class="b2">
      <inner>
        test
      </inner>
      <tab>
        <icon class="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/></svg></icon>
      </tab>
    </bar>

    <bar class="b3">
      <inner>
        test
      </inner>
      <tab>
        <icon class="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/></svg></icon>
      </tab>
    </bar>

    <bar class="b4">
      <inner>
        test
      </inner>
      <tab>
        <icon class="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/></svg></icon>
      </tab>
    </bar>

    <bar class="b5">
      <inner>
        test
      </inner>
      <tab>
        <icon class="plus"><svg viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon points="28,12.5 15.5,12.5 15.5,0 12.5,0 12.5,12.5 0,12.5 0,15.5 12.5,15.5 12.5,28 15.5,28 15.5,15.5 28,15.5 "/></svg></icon>
      </tab>
    </bar>

  </wrapper>

</body>

</html>



I tried it at first with the addClass and removeClass button, and working with .close and .open classes on the divs, but that also did not work. Then I figured it might work with toggleClass but still didn't change anything.

Are there any JS errors in the dev console?

There's nothing in your code that checks for all the colored tabs being closed and treats this as a special case to open the grey tab.

Note that the selector $(".b2.open tab") only selects the element that has class="b2 open" class when the page is first loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670732/jquery-how-can-i-use-event-delegation-with-classes-added-to-nested-divs for how to use delegation to deal with dynamically changing the open class.

If you modified your logic such that you had just one event handler that checked the current status of the clicked tab, you could then either open that tab while closing all other tabs, or close that tab and open the grey tab. The logic for all of them would be effectively identical, except for clicking the grey tab when it is the one that is open, assuming you want to prevent closing it. Each tab having it's own logic just complicates your process.

I am able to work with less functions (using the same one for all tabs), but I can't seem to find a way to make Javascript check for any updated classes of the elements or something like that. Is there any action that I could add to the end of each function that that will check for any updates in classes?

CSS is automatically updated when classes are changed; if you need to run javascript based on a certain class, you would need to write that function and call it when the class(es) change.

I can't seem to find a piece of script code that makes javascript re-scan the page to be able to respond to updated class changes. Anyone that can help?

Sorry, figured it out due to the link in the comment of @Barmar . Thanks a lot!!
